# Google Analytics -- Question on how it affects search results on Google

Tags: google-analytics

Simple true or false:  Having Google Analytics installed on your page will automatically cause that page to be indexed by Google and appear in their search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new awesome site for answer this kind of questions: [WebApps @ StackExchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). I think you will get better answers there.